# To open different links using window.open()

Tags: javascript, jsf, hyperlink

I have a dataTable in which one of the columns contains URLs. On click of those links I have to open respective link in a new page. I am using `window.open()` to open those links.
It's opening a new window but not displaying the page. The javascript code I am using is:

```
function openDisclaimer(objectId)
{
var disclaimerID = objectId.id;
var url = document.getElementById(objectId).value;
window.open(url);
}
```

and

```
<h:commandLink id="dsclaimLink" value="#{managePersonalization.disclaimerURL}" onclick="openDisclaimer(this);" >
```

Comment: You have JSF, which generates JavaScript+HTML, which produces an output. You are only showing us the two ends. Where is the problem occurring? Is the generated HTML+JavaScript not as you expect or is the result you get not what you expect from that generated HTML+JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

First, in ancient JSF versions there was a bug which caused that commandlinks can't work that way. Ensure that you're using the latest version/build. Mojarra is available [here](http://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net) and MyFaces is available [here](http://myfaces.apache.org).

As to your actual problem, a commandlink basically generates a link which **submits the parent form**. It's supposed to be placed inside a `h:form`, but here you just want a *plain vanilla* link. In this case, replace it by `h:outputLink`. Don't forget to add `return false;` to end of click event to block the link's default action.

```
<h:outputLink 
    value="#{managePersonalization.disclaimerURL}" 
    onclick="openDisclaimer(this); return false;">
    <h:outputText value="Disclaimer" />
</h:outputLink>
```

Further, the `value` attribute actually ends up as `href` attribute of the generated `<a>` element, so your JavaScript needs to be fixed that it gets the URL from `href` attribute rather than the `value` attribute (JavaScript doesn't see the JSF source code, but only its generated HTML output!):

```
function openDisclaimer(link) {
    window.open(link.href);
}
```

You also see that `document.getElementById` is removed because it makes no sense as you **already** have the sole element as function argument! ;)

You can even get rid of the whole function:

```
<h:outputLink 
    value="#{managePersonalization.disclaimerURL}" 
    onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">
    <h:outputText value="Disclaimer" />
</h:outputLink>
```

*Alternatively*, if you actually want a worthfully tab/window instead of a **popup** window, then you can also just make use of the `target` attribute which you set to `_blank`:

```
<h:outputLink 
    value="#{managePersonalization.disclaimerURL}" 
    target="_blank">
    <h:outputText value="Disclaimer" />
</h:outputLink>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I tried above code snippet.In Mozilla, its giving error "c is not registered protocol" & in IE its giving 'Access Denied'

Comment: I tried it with h:commandLink also. It is opening the same page inspite of link.

Comment: It's `h:outputLink`, **output** Link. Did you add `return false;`? Did you specify a **correct** URL? Do you have the recent JSF version? Is the `onclick` attribute generated in HTML output? Did you try the `target` attribute? Popups triggered by `window.open` are often blocked in modern browsers. Update your question with the  the generated HTML output if you want better assistance.

Comment: I added return false; url is correct . target attrbute tried.

Comment: 1) Upgrade to 1.1_02 https://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net/files/documents/1866/33714/jsf-1_1_02.zip 2) Please update question with generated HTML output if you want better assistance (after upgrading to 1.1_02 and testing with it!).

Comment: This doesn't represent a `h:outputLink` and the onclick is missing. You're likely using `t:inputFileUpload` or something similar. When posting JSF problems, please post the **real** components used and don't obfuscate the original/3rdparty used components with other or standard components.

Comment: See, I have uploaded the link first using t:inputFileUpload and added to the datatable. The next step i need is i want the link to get opened in a new page. so what source should i send to make it clear

Comment: How to make the thing clear to you... As Bozho said it may be some url problem... html code when i click on the link is
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('file://C:/html/a.html');;return oamSubmitForm('form1','form1:details:0:dsclaimLink');" id="form1:details:0:dsclaimLink">file://C:/html/a.html</a>

Comment: C:/html/a.html is the link i have added to the datatable and form1:details:0:dsclaimLink" is the id for the h:commandLink

Comment: Getting following error in mozilla Security Error: Content at http://localhost:9080/WEB/addPers.faces may not load or link to file:///C:/html/a.html.

Comment: Don't use `file://` links. Use `http://` links. Create a FileServlet if necessary: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like this:

```
<h:commandLink id="dsclaimLink" value="#{managePersonalization.disclaimerURL}" 
    onclick="window.open('#{managePersonalization.disclaimerURL}');" />
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.
Its giving javascript error ") expected"

Comment: well, just add the single-quote. I've forgotten it.

Comment: what does the generated javascript look like?

Comment: then your URL is wrong. That's why me and BalusC want the generated javascript. Go to View Source and see.

Answer (score -1):

Just check what does objectID returns

Comment: I am calling js on following:
<h:commandLink id="dsclaimLink" value="#{managePersonalization.disclaimerURL}" onclick="openDisclaimer(this);" >  
Its giving ID for this 
http://localhost:9080/WEB/addPers.faces#

Comment: Its the Id of the cell of dataTable